# Combining responses from multiple XSLTs using another XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have three XSLT files which gives output in the following format(similar output for all three XSLTs)

```
    <Reports>
        <Report>
            <a>1</a>
            <b>2</b>
            <c>3</c>
        </Report>
        <Report>
            <a>4</a>
            <b>5</b>
            <c>6</c>
        </Report>
    <Reports>
```

Is it possible to merge these three outputs so that, all Report nodes are child of a single Reports node, instead of three?

Comment: You can process secondary input documents in XSLT, it doesn't matter whether produced by XSLT or not, using the XSLT `document` function e.g. `document('file1.xml') | document('file2.xml') | document('file3.xml')`. The function also allows you to pull in an XML document (e.g. `files.xml`) somehow listing other files e.g. `<files><file>file1.xml</file><file>file2.xml</file><file>file3.xml</file></files>` and doing e.g. `document(document('files.xml')/files/file)` to pull in the files listed in the document.

Comment: @MartinHonnen I have three responses which constantly changes with a SOAP request, and not stored in any document

Comment: You will need to tell us more about the context in which you use XSLT and what having "three outputs" or "three responses" means. Which XSLT processor do you use, how do you run it?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's easy to write an XSLT transformation that takes three input documents (which might be the output of other transformations) and merges them.

The way you combine multiple transformations into a workflow or pipeline depends on your preferred technology platform. Some candidates: Ant, Gradle, XProc. Or you can even do the coordination in XSLT itself, since (in XSLT 3.0) one transformation can invoke another using the fn:transform() function.